# MongoDB update using Java 3 driver

Tags: mongodb-java

I'm switching to the MongoDB Java driver version 3. I cannot figure out how to perform an update of a Document. For example, I want to change the "age" of an user:

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("exampledb");
MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> coll = db.getCollection("collusers");

Document doc1 = new Document("name", "frank").append("age", 55) .append("phone", "123-456-789");
Document doc2 = new Document("name", "frank").append("age", 33) .append("phone", "123-456-789");
coll.updateOne(doc1, doc2);
```

The output is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name name
```

Any idea how to fix it ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use:

```
coll.updateOne(eq("name", "frank"), new Document("$set", new Document("age", 33)));
```

for updating the first Document found. For multiple updates:

```
coll.updateMany(eq("name", "frank"), new Document("$set", new Document("age", 33)));
```

On this link, you can fine a [quick reference to MongoDB Java 3 Driver](http://www.mastertheintegration.com/nosql-databases/mongodb/mongodb-java-driver-3-0-quick-reference.html)

Comment: What what what??? `$set` is Jiffa!!! Who thought of this implicit/hidden directive? What does it actually mean in comparison to other _i don't know_ implicit/hidden directives?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, I don't know what "Jiffa" means but I certain we're very much in agreement about the crazy way in which the set command is passed to the server.  The driver should have wrapped `$set`, `$inc` etc.

Comment: @Paul Japan International Freight Forwarders Association, Inc, apparently.

Comment: how can this be achieved with helper functions? `eq(...), set(new Document("age",33))` does not seem to work for some reason

Answer (score 11):

in Mongodb Java driver 3.0 , when you update a document, you can call the coll.replaceOne method to replace document, or call the coll.updateOne / coll.updateMany method to update document(s) by using $set/$setOnInsert/etc operators.

in your case, you can try:

```
coll.updateOne(eq("name", "frank"), new Document("$set", new Document("age", 33)));
coll.replaceOne(eq("name", "frank"), new Document("age", 33));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
coll.findOneAndReplace(doc1, doc2);
```